# Javascript var, let and function

Tags: javascript, hoisting

```js
    let x = '1'
    function first(){
        console.log(x)
    }
    x='2'
    function second(){
        let x='3'
        first()
    }
    second()
```

My question is , why is the answer '2' instead of '3'?
I know let is block scope and var is function scope,but I just do not get this right. Please help me here, many thx!

Comment: because `let x='3'` scope is in `second`, but the `console.log(x)` is in `first` ... so the global `x` is the `x` it logs - note the scoping of `let` vs `var` is NOT at play - if you used `var` instead of `let`, the result would be the same - also, since your outer `let` is in the global scope, and the inner `let` is in the function scope, there is no "block scope" at play either

Comment: @DBS - there is no `this` involved, so the scoping of above variables would not change

Comment: Because let x = '3' is not global  variable. and let x = '1'; is global variable used in all place.  and in next step you can change x value 1 to 2. that why your Ans is 2.

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning **3** to a local variable, it only has an effect inside the **second** function

This example works:

```js
let x = '1'

function first(){
    console.log(x)
}

x='2'

function second(){
    x='3'
    first()
}

second()
```

Answer (score 1):

initially the function `first` has no idea what x is about. so it automatically searched in the upper scope.

gladly, on the global scope there is `x` definition.

Therefore, as this script got initialized, the function `console.log` in function `first` reserve the memory address of `x`, and watches that **global** variable all along.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `shadowing`.

In JavaScript, variables with the same name can be specified at multiple layers of nested scope. In such a situation, local variables gain priority over global variables. If you declare a local variable and a global variable with the same name, the local variable will take precedence when you use it inside a function or block.

And in your case, there is no local variable define inside your `first()` function so it will take the value of `x = 2` of the global variable.

```js
let x = '1'

function first() {
  console.log(x)
}
x = '2'

function second() {
  let x = '3'
  first()
}
second()
```

See the below code, If you've declared `x=4` inside `first()` then it will return the value `4 instead of 2`

```js
let x = '1'

function first() {
  x = '4'
  console.log(x)
}
x = '2'

function second() {
  let x = '3'
  first()
}
second()
```

Check out this if you want to know more about `JavaScript Variable Scope and Hoisting`: https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/